# DomPDF strange padding

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I have an issue with `dompdf` where it shows me strange padding all the time that should not be there.

[image]

Above is the image where it is happening where my html itself i just a simple 1

tag with some text in it.

I initiate the library as:

```
class OmnPdf extends \Dompdf\Dompdf
{
    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        if($options == null){
            $options = new \Dompdf\Options();
        }
        $options->setIsPhpEnabled(true);
        $options->setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true); // For combining multiple pdf outputs
        $options->setIsFontSubsettingEnabled(true);
        $options->setDefaultPaperSize('A4');
        $options->setDebugCss(true);
        $options->setDebugLayout(true);
        $options->setDpi(72);

        parent::__construct($options);
    }
}
```

What i am expecting is that the text will be alligned according the outer page (see red line).

Thanks,
Pim

Comment: Per comments below, what if you use some other font (specifically one of the DejaVu fonts or a core font such as Helvetica)? Also, can you show you HTML and share the font you are using? And how did you load the font into dompdf?

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading a custom font? Because I'm pretty sure this is causing your issue.

Comment: Yes seems to be related but how can a font affect this? Its a normal TTF font which is loaded

Comment: Normally this is caused by the font metrics, you should include this file in DOMPDF.